# How can i only apply animation for activity but not for toolbar?

Tags: android

I have several activities which have the same toolbar at bottom of each activity. The problem that i'm encountering is when i apply animation slide in/out for all activities, the whole of activity will be applied this animation. But i don't want toolbar do this animation. I mean that when i move from an activity to another activity ,all other views of activity will be move but the toolbar don't move.

How can i achieve this?

Thanks you a lot.

/***********Edit*****************/

I intend to use TabWidget with activity tabs, but i don't know how to use overridePendingTransition() to make a transition animation between them when i change tabs. I also tried to put overridePendingTransition() in pause event of TabActivity and Activities for tabs, but not work.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

if activities are not to complex you can do animation on layouts with change content view (or change view to invisible). Another option it to create tabwidget and just change tabs with animation between them. Third option is to turn off animation between activities changing, that create illusion that toolbar is staying. Just add animation to main layouts.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, my activities have many child views and contain toolbar (this is a custom view). I used overridePendingTransition(mEnterAnim, mExitAnim) in resume event to do animation slide in/out for activities. how can i only apply animation for specific views and not for specific views?

Comment: you need to create a reference to xml file. Try to keep all elements what you want to move on one layout, than create the reference and animate it. This is not a perfect solution for your app, cause to add new element to stage the old need to disappear what leave screen empty for half second. To create reference just implement new View and do findViewById method. Off course if you use xmls files.

Comment: i used to think about using tabwidget, but i don't know how can i use animation between them. that is an activity tab not a view tab. if possible, can you give a reference of using animation between activity tabs in tabwidget?

Comment: with tabwidget gonna be the same like with other activities, You still will have empty screen between end/start animations. You just create animation onResume method. If you want to have really nice and smooth animation maybe try ViewFlipper or SlidingDrawer.

Comment: ViewFlipper or SlidingDrawer is really nice and smooth animation, but i think it is not suitable for my case. my app have lot of nested activities, TabWidget is look like ok but i dont know how to use overridePendingTransition to make a transition between activities tab.

Comment: I dont if it possible to add overridePendingTransition in TabWidget.